# Javascript: Copied Variables and Prototypes

Tags: javascript

Okay, so Javascript is a 'prototype' language, which to my understanding means it has things like this:

```
var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
c.ctx = c.getContext('2d');
```

Now, if I do this:

```
var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
c.ctx = c.getContext('2d');
c = document.getElementById('newCanvas');
```

Will c.ctx remain and be functional while affecting a totally new canvas?  Thanks!

My experiments are saying no, but I ask because perhaps I am missing something.  If in theory this should NOT work, do you have any good ways of getting around it relatively easily?  (Or not so easily, but easily is the preference of course!)

Comment: No, because you re-define the variable.

Comment: what do you mean by "remain and be functional while affecting a totally new canvas?", c.ctx will be defined as long as the function containing c.ctx is in scope.

Comment: Try not to mix JavaScript with the DOM. They are two totally different things. You're not using prototypes anywhere in your code. All you're doing is getting a DOM element in a variable `c`, assigning a property to it and then reassigning the variable `c` to another DOM element. There's no inheritance in your code. To understand precisely what prototypal inheritance is I suggest you read [Why Prototypal Inheritance Matters](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters "Aadit M Shah | Why Prototypal Inheritance Matters").

Answer (score 2):

> Will `c.ctx` remain and be functional while affecting a totally new canvas?

Nope, you're creating an entirely new reference for `c`.

> so Javascript is a 'prototype' language

Why not define what you want in the *prototype* then?

```
Object.defineProperty(
    HTMLCanvasElement.prototype,
    'ctx',
    {
        'get': function () { return this.getContext('2d'); },
        'configurable': true
    }
);
```

Now all `<canvas>` elements when accessed though their DOM Interface will have a property *ctx* which *gets* their context.

If you're happy with the *context* being cached, you could use this instead

```
function () { return this.ctx = this.getContext('2d'); }
```

which sets a new property on the instance which shadows the prototype's getter.

Comment: Clever! I wonder what the overhead is for having to call `getContext` every time `ctx` is accessed.

Comment: I'm not sure how multiple "contexts" work, but you could always do `return this.ctx = this.getContext('2d');` so you cache it, instead

Answer (score 1):

When you assign this:

```
c = document.getElementById('newCanvas');
```

you are replacing the entire `c` variable with a reference to a new object.  No previous properties of the former `c` object will remain.

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
c.ctx = c.getContext('2d');
c = document.getElementById('newCanvas');
```

At the last line, you're simply overwriting the c variable.

You could think of it as running this

```
var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
c.ctx = c.getContext('2d');
c = 3;
```

Assuming the code you wrote actually meant something: You're in luck though, a ctx has a canvas reference built-in (it's the opposite of what you wanted, but it's the same deal)

```
ctx.canvas;
```